# Set Mouse Left Handed on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, mouse, touchpad, accessibility

I can't set lubuntu mouse/touchpad to left hand

I tried this:

```
bruno@lubuntu:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳  USB OPTICAL MOUSE                        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ MSI WMI hotkeys                           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
bruno@lubuntu:~$ xinput set-button-map 12 3 2 1
bruno@lubuntu:~$ xinput set-button-map 10 3 2 1
```

Ok, this works perfectly, but every time I shutdown or reboot I lose this config.

How keep it permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/desktop.conf`

It should look like this:

```
[Mouse]
AccFactor=20
AccThreshold=10
LeftHanded=1
```